# Fireplace update allowed but set fails with "Simulated set denied"

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have these rules

```
{
    "rules": {
        "categories": { ".read": true },
        "conversations": {
            "$key": {

                "users": {
                    ".write": true
                   
                },
            }
        },
```

I tried to post to `/conversations/44da/` this data:

```
{
  "users": "value"
}
```

which works fine with using update method
[image]

but set fails

[image]

Comment: Please, share the full window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you update, you save the data to the user node. This means searching for rules in the database will find "write true" on line 8.

But when you set a new value, you write in node $ key (44da) (because the user does not exist yet), or even in node "conversations" (in case node 44da does not exist either). The database searches for rules for the conversation of the $ key node or node, but no rules are set there.

Comment: dang what a gotcha, and great answer thx, you must be a real pro at FB

Comment: not real pro at all, i`m just currently working with it and meet with most this bugs on my own

Comment: This seems like a real limitation or oversight tbh